# How many times does each number occur in given cocountble sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Suppose that we are given uncountable number of cocountable (in $\mathbb{R}$) sets. For every $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ let $S_{\alpha}$ be the set of those given cocountable sets, for which $\alpha$ is their member. Is it true that there exists at least one $\alpha$, such that $S_{\alpha}$ is uncountable?

It is easy to see that there is infinite $S_{\alpha}$, since we can extract countable number of cocountable sets and their intersection is not empty (intersecting cocountable sets is pretty much the same as taking a union of countable sets — and taking a countable union of countable sets cannot give the whole $\mathbb{R}$).
How to proceed further? Can you give any hints?

Answer (score 2):

The problem, as you've phrased it, is independent of $\sf ZFC$.

The exact same argument you give shows that if $\sf CH$ is false, then your statement is always true: the union of less than $\mathfrak c$-many countable sets cannot be all of $\mathbb R,$ so any subcollection of the co-countable sets of size, say, $\aleph_1$ will have nonempty intersection.

If $\sf CH$ is true, write $\mathbb R = \{r_{\alpha}: \alpha<\aleph_1\}.$ Then let $A_\alpha = \{r_\beta: \beta > \alpha\}$ for $\alpha < \aleph_1.$ Then the $(A_\alpha:\alpha <\aleph_1)$ are an uncountable collection of co-countable sets and each $r_\beta$ is in only countably many.

Answer (score -1):

there are atleast countably infinite such '$\alpha$'.

here is a proof using simple logic -

" Suppose that we are given uncountable number of cocountable (in R
) sets. For every $\alpha$∈R
let $S_\alpha$
be the set of those given cocountable sets, for which α
is their member. Is it true that there exists at least one $\alpha$
, such that $S_\alpha$
is uncountable? "

i can give an instance of this general problem -

let L be a set of all singleton sets containing an irrational number ( its obvious that no 2 elements in L will be equal ). - L is uncountable, although its elements are 'countable sets'

let M be a set of all sets such that each set is a complement of one and only one set contained by L , in the set of Real numbers , as an element - M will be uncountable, - Each set contained by M is a complement of a singleton set in the set of real numbers, thus they are all uncountable, each set will be missing exactly one irrational number, - every set in M is a cocountable set in R

Now, since  every set in M contains all the rationals, and there are countably infinite rationals, thus there are countably infinite numbers who will be a member in all those cocountable sets contained by M.

hence, there are countably infinite '$\alpha$' ,

edit -
infact there will be uncountably many such '$\alpha$' , if you you consider irrational numbers, since each irrational number will be missing in exactly one of the uncountably many cocountable sets in M,